# What is the difference between python3 -m pip and pip3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

What is the difference between these:

```
sudo python3 -m pip install requests pyarrow
sudo pip3 install requests pyarrow
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+What+is+the+difference+between+%22python+-m+pip%22+pip

Answer (score 0):

First of all `sudo` (short for superuser do) runs the program as an administrator. Second, `python3` will either open the live interpreter or a script passed to it as an argument, while `pip3` is used to install python packages.

In your given usage, they should do the same thing.